# Recover list format when passing an argument

Tags: python, string, list, parsing

I am passing as argument to a python program a list of two strings (in particular to stream geo located tweets from python-twitter). The format is as example: 
    `my_python_program.py -l ['-9.215752,36.99','3.73,42.139225']`
But when I "argparse" to get that argument I see it is passed as "string" :
    `"['-9.215752,36.99','3.73,42.139225']"`

I could recover the original format looking for the "[" "," and "]" character and getting the string between them. But I guess there should be a more "pythonic" way of doing that?

Comment: `import ast`, then `ast.literal_eval(your_string)`.

Comment: Thanks Austin!...I got it!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as comments noted, `literal_eval` is what you want here.

`ast.literal_eval(my_str)` will give you a parsed object. Just `import ast` and `literal_eval` what comes from argparse.